# How I can send a parameter from a servlet to a jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, setattribute

The form is submitted by javascript, but the servlet returns a null attribute to the jsp, I think this line request.getRequestDispatcher ("views / Upload.jsp") forward (request, response) not runs. I leave the code:

**Upload.jsp**

```
   <form id="upload" method="post" action="../Upload_Servlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>                                
                <input  name="fileName" id="fileName" type="text" style="visibility: hidden" value="<%=request.getAttribute("logotipo")%>">
            </div>

            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>
            <div id="tudiv"></div>
            <input type="button" id="Aceptar" value="Aceptar">

        </form>
```

**Upload_Servlet.java**

```
          if (!fi.isFormField()) {
          // Get the uploaded file parameters
          String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();

          String fileName = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1) + fi.getName();
          request.setAttribute("logotipo", fileName);
          String contentType = fi.getContentType();
          boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
          long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
          // Write the file
          if (fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0) {
              file = new File(filePath
                      + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
          } else {
              file = new File(filePath
                      + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
          }
          fi.write(file);
          out.println("Archivo subido: " + fileName + "<br>");
          request.getRequestDispatcher("vistas/Upload.jsp").forward(request, response);
      }
```

**script.js**

```
    $('#upload').fileupload({

    // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
    dropZone: $('#drop'),

    // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
    // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
    add: function (e, data) {

        var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
            ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

        // Append the file name and file size
        tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                     .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');


        // Add the HTML to the UL element
        data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

        // Initialize the knob plugin
        tpl.find('input').knob
```

Comment: Have you debugged your servlet code to check if you are indeed setting the `logotipo` attribute on your request?

Comment: Does escaping the double quotes helps `value="<%=request.getAttribute(\"logotipo\")%>"`

Comment: Yes I have debugged, but returns null, do not know why not send the value of `fileName`

Comment: Instead of forwarding the same request object, create a new request object and froward that. The fact that the original request object is multipart/form-data could possibly be causing the problem.

Comment: @ThankYouSTR T tried escaping the double quotes, but maybe the problem is that the en `request.getRequestDispacher("vistas/Upload.jsp").forward (request, response)` not execute and not send the attribute

Comment: Does this line set null to the filename variable? `String fileName = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1) + fi.getName();`

Comment: @developerwjk I changed the request object , now I do it from a servlet `Sur_servlet: ` `request.getRequestDispatcher("vistas/Upload.jsp").forward (request, response);` submits the form but not go to the servlet Upload_Servlet   and not executed this line  `request.getRequestDispatcher ("vistas/ Upload.jsp").forward(request, response);` but stays in the same servlet `Sur_servlet`

Comment: @Everton Agner I use this line to the file name will add a ramdom and thus more difficult than the file name this repeated and is replaced. And the file uploaded  with the ramdom + the name of the original file, but I need to get this value in jsp fileName to save that value in DB

Comment: You should save the value in the db in the servlet not the JSP. Make the servlet do all updates to server and JSP just display stuff.  Not that this fixes your problem. And what I suggested earlier apparently can't be done, although I could have sworn I'd seen it done before.

Comment: Yes I save the value from a servlet in the database, but what I needed was to get the value of the variable fileName in  Upload.jsp then send it to another jsp to thereafter submit the form and save the data from a servlet. And the problem which does not work the setAttribute () is because it is being submitted from javascript and it does not work from a third party.

Comment: Thank you all for responding and help me and based in ideas that emerged  now it succeeds